# How to read only 5 last line of the text file in PHP?

Tags: php, fopen

I have a file named `file.txt` which is update by adding lines to it.

I am reading it by this code:

```
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$data = "";
while(!feof($fp))
{
$data .= fgets($fp, 4096);
}
echo $data;
```

and a huge number of lines appears. 
I just want to echo the last 5 lines of the file

How can I do that ?

---

The `file.txt` is like this:

```
11111111111111
22222222222

33333333333333
44444444444

55555555555555
66666666666
```

Comment: Are the lines of fixed width in bytes?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025877/995958

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Untested code, but should work:

```
$file = file("filename.txt");
for ($i = max(0, count($file)-6); $i < count($file); $i++) {
  echo $file[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Calling `max` will handle the file being less than 6 lines.

Comment: what if filename.txt only contains 3 lines?

Comment: this is good , but need note a Critical issues. that is $i may be less than 0;  so you need this if ($i > 0) echo ....

Comment: Not very good, as this consumes a lot of RAM for nothing in case the log file is big.

Comment: The terrible code in terms of memory usage. It puts the whole file in memory. If that file will be super big you are in trouble.

Answer (score 52):

For a large file, reading all the lines into an array with file() is a bit wasteful. Here's how you could read the file and maintain a buffer of the last 5 lines:

```
$lines=array();
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while(!feof($fp))
{
   $line = fgets($fp, 4096);
   array_push($lines, $line);
   if (count($lines)>5)
       array_shift($lines);
}
fclose($fp);
```

You could optimize this a bit more with some heuristics about likely line length by seeking to a position, say, approx 10 lines from the end, and going further back if that doesn't yield 5 lines. Here's a simple implementation which demonstrates that:

```
//how many lines?
$linecount=5;

//what's a typical line length?
$length=40;

//which file?
$file="test.txt";

//we double the offset factor on each iteration
//if our first guess at the file offset doesn't
//yield $linecount lines
$offset_factor=1;


$bytes=filesize($file);

$fp = fopen($file, "r") or die("Can't open $file");


$complete=false;
while (!$complete)
{
    //seek to a position close to end of file
    $offset = $linecount * $length * $offset_factor;
    fseek($fp, -$offset, SEEK_END);


    //we might seek mid-line, so read partial line
    //if our offset means we're reading the whole file, 
    //we don't skip...
    if ($offset<$bytes)
        fgets($fp);

    //read all following lines, store last x
    $lines=array();
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        $line = fgets($fp);
        array_push($lines, $line);
        if (count($lines)>$linecount)
        {
            array_shift($lines);
            $complete=true;
        }
    }

    //if we read the whole file, we're done, even if we
    //don't have enough lines
    if ($offset>=$bytes)
        $complete=true;
    else
        $offset_factor*=2; //otherwise let's seek even further back

}
fclose($fp);

var_dump($lines);
```

Comment: @Paual Dixon, In while loop you read all line and store last X line. is it possible to read last X lines?

Answer (score 17):

If you're on a linux system you could do this:

```
$lines = `tail -5 /path/to/file.txt`;
```

Comment: The file array slice is not a great method for large memory files. ```tail``` is the direction I went with.

Answer (score 16):

Opening large files with `file()` can generate a large array, reserving a considerable chunk of memory.

You can reduce the memory cost with `SplFileObject` since it iterates through each line.

Use the `seek` method (of `seekableiterator`) to fetch the last line. You should then subtract the current key value by 5.

To obtain the last line, use `PHP_INT_MAX`. (Yes, this is a workaround.)

```
$file = new SplFileObject('large_file.txt', 'r');

$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);

$last_line = $file->key();

$lines = new LimitIterator($file, $last_line - 5, $last_line);

print_r(iterator_to_array($lines));
```

Comment: I recommend this as fast method for large files

Comment: This solution has to read every single line from the file, which make its complexity O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the fseek()-based solutions, which means the time it takes would depend on the file size, the bigger the slower.

Answer (score 13):

```
function ReadFromEndByLine($filename,$lines)
{

        /* freely customisable number of lines read per time*/
        $bufferlength = 5000;

        $handle = @fopen($filename, "r");
        if (!$handle) {
                echo "Error: can't find or open $filename<br/>\n";
                return -1;
        }

        /*get the file size with a trick*/
        fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
        $filesize = ftell($handle);

        /*don't want to get past the start-of-file*/
        $position= - min($bufferlength,$filesize);

        while ($lines > 0) {

                if ($err=fseek($handle,$position,SEEK_END)) {  /* should not happen but it's better if we check it*/
                        echo "Error $err: something went wrong<br/>\n";
                        fclose($handle);
                        return $lines;
                }

                /* big read*/
                $buffer = fread($handle,$bufferlength);

                /* small split*/
                $tmp = explode("\n",$buffer);

                /*previous read could have stored a partial line in $aliq*/
                if ($aliq != "") {

                                /*concatenate current last line with the piece left from the previous read*/
                                $tmp[count($tmp)-1].=$aliq;
                }

                /*drop first line because it may not be complete*/
                $aliq = array_shift($tmp);

                $read = count($tmp);
                if ( $read >= $lines ) {   /*have read too much!*/

                        $tmp2 = array_slice($tmp,$read-$n);
                        /* merge it with the array which will be returned by the function*/
                        $lines = array_merge($tmp2,$lines);

                        /* break the cycle*/
                        $lines = 0;
                } elseif (-$position >= $filesize) {  /* haven't read enough but arrived at the start of file*/

                        //get back $aliq which contains the very first line of the file
                        $lines = array_merge($aliq,$tmp,$lines);

                        //force it to stop reading
                        $lines = 0;

                } else {              /*continue reading...*/

                        //add the freshly grabbed lines on top of the others
                        $lines = array_merge($tmp,$lines);

                        $lines -= $read;

                        //next time we want to read another block
                        $position -= $bufferlength;

                        //don't want to get past the start of file
                        $position = max($position, -$filesize);
                }
        }
        fclose($handle);

        return $lines;
}
```

This will be fast for larger files but alot of code for a simple task, if there LARGE FILES, use this

ReadFromEndByLine('myFile.txt',6);

Comment: This requires reading the entire file into memory, which may be very bad.

Comment: Updated with a larger block of code but yet faster and less memory usage. - Taken from http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=197

Comment: `while ($lines > 0) {` gives undefined variable notice

Answer (score 13):

This is a common interview question.  Here's what I wrote last year when I was asked this question.  Remember that code you get on Stack Overflow is licensed with the [Creative Commons Share-Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

```
<?php

/**
 * Demonstrate an efficient way to search the last 100 lines of a file
 * containing roughly ten million lines for a sample string. This should
 * function without having to process each line of the file (and without making
 * use of the “tail” command or any external system commands). 
 * Attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961731/3389585
 */

$filename = '/opt/local/apache2/logs/karwin-access_log';
$searchString = 'index.php';
$numLines = 100;
$maxLineLength = 200;

$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

$data = fseek($fp, -($numLines * $maxLineLength), SEEK_END);

$lines = array();
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $lines[] = fgets($fp);
}

$c = count($lines);
$i = $c >= $numLines? $c-$numLines: 0;
for (; $i<$c; ++$i) {
  if ($pos = strpos($lines[$i], $searchString)) {
    echo $lines[$i];
  }
}
```

This solution does make an assumption about the maximum line length.  The interviewer asked me how I would solve the problem if I couldn't make that assumption, and had to accommodate lines that were potentially longer than any max length I chose.

I told him that any software project has to make certain assumptions, but I could test if `$c` was less than the desired number of lines, and if it isn't, `fseek()` back further incrementally (doubling each time) until we do get enough lines.

Comment: `$data` is set but never used. Are you confident this snippet will `echo` any matching lines?

Comment: @mjohns It was 10 years ago, but I recall I did test it. The return value of [fseek()](https://www.php.net/fseek) in PHP is simply 0 on success or -1 on failure. I agree it would be appropriate to check this status.

Answer (score 11):

### FAST

Here is FAST method for MEDIUM size files with LOW memory cost (low even for large files) - I develop [Wallace Maxters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981383/860099) (if you want to upvote - do it on his answer) by wrap his code inside handy function and add reverse feature

```
function readLastLines($filename, $num, $reverse = false)
{
    $file = new \SplFileObject($filename, 'r');
    $file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $last_line = $file->key();
    $lines = new \LimitIterator($file, $last_line - $num, $last_line);
    $arr = iterator_to_array($lines);
    if($reverse) $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    return implode('',$arr);
}

// use it by
$lines = readLastLines("file.txt", 5) // return string with 5 last lines
```

Comment: Clean and simple, without unnecessarily classes and class methods - thank you.

Comment: Just use `max($num, $last_line - $num)` instead of `$last_line - $num` to make sure there will no be negative offset, or PHP shows error.

Comment: This solution has to read every single line from the file, which make its complexity O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the fseek()-based solutions, which means the time it takes would depend on the file size, the bigger the slower.

Answer (score 9):

The most of options here suppose to read file into the memory and then work with rows. This wouldnt be a good idea, if the file too large

I think the best way is to use some OS-utility, like 'tail' in unix.

```
exec('tail -3 /logs/reports/2017/02-15/173606-arachni-2415.log', $output);
echo $output;

// 2017-02-15 18:03:25 [*] Path Traversal: Analyzing response ...
// 2017-02-15 18:03:27 [*] Path Traversal: Analyzing response ...
// 2017-02-15 18:03:27 [*] Path Traversal: Analyzing response ...
```

Comment: `$output` is an array, so if you're echoing then you'd need to use implode()

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't use `file()` so it will be more efficient for huge files;

```
<?php
function read_backward_line($filename, $lines, $revers = false)
{
    $offset = -1;
    $c = '';
    $read = '';
    $i = 0;
    $fp = @fopen($filename, "r");
    while( $lines && fseek($fp, $offset, SEEK_END) >= 0 ) {
        $c = fgetc($fp);
        if($c == "\n" || $c == "\r"){
            $lines--;
            if( $revers ){
                $read[$i] = strrev($read[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        if( $revers ) $read[$i] .= $c;
        else $read .= $c;
        $offset--;
    }
    fclose ($fp);
    if( $revers ){
        if($read[$i] == "\n" || $read[$i] == "\r")
            array_pop($read);
        else $read[$i] = strrev($read[$i]);
        return implode('',$read);
    }
    return strrev(rtrim($read,"\n\r"));
}
//if $revers=false function return->
//line 1000: i am line of 1000
//line 1001: and i am line of 1001
//line 1002: and i am last line
//but if $revers=true function return->
//line 1002: and i am last line
//line 1001: and i am line of 1001
//line 1000: i am line of 1000
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This function will work for REALLY large files under 4GB. The speed comes from reading a big chunk of data instead of 1 byte at a time and counting lines.

```
// Will seek backwards $n lines from the current position
function seekLineBackFast($fh, $n = 1){
    $pos = ftell($fh);
    if ($pos == 0)
        return false;

    $posAtStart = $pos;

    $readSize = 2048*2;
    $pos = ftell($fh);
    if(!$pos){
            fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
            return false;
    }

    // we want to seek 1 line before the line we want.
    // so that we can start at the very beginning of the line
    while ($n >= 0) {
        if($pos == 0)
                    break;
            $pos -= $readSize;
            if($pos <= 0){
                    $pos = 0;
            }

            // fseek returns 0 on success and -1 on error
            if(fseek($fh, $pos, SEEK_SET)==-1){
                    fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    break;
            }
            $data = fread($fh, $readSize);
            $count = substr_count($data, "\n");
            $n -= $count;

            if($n < 0)
                    break;
    }
    fseek($fh, $pos, SEEK_SET);
    // we may have seeked too far back
    // so we read one line at a time forward
    while($n < 0){
            fgets($fh);
            $n++;
    }
    // just in case?
    $pos = ftell($fh);
    if(!$pos)
        fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // check that we have indeed gone back
    if ($pos >= $posAtStart)
        return false;

    return $pos;
}
```

After running above function, you can just do fgets() in a loop to read each line at a time from $fh.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [file()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function reads the whole file into an array.
This solution requires the least amount of typing:

```
$data = array_slice(file('file.txt'), -5);

foreach ($data as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution! Thanks!

Comment: @undo it's not "awesome" because it "reads **the whole file** into an array", so it can be suitable for very small files only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my small helper library (2 functions)

https://github.com/jasir/file-helpers

Then just use:

```
//read last 5 lines
$lines = \jasir\FileHelpers\FileHelpers::readLastLines($pathToFile, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tested this one. It works for me.

```
function getlast($filename,$linenum_to_read,$linelength){

   // this function takes 3 arguments;


   if (!$linelength){ $linelength = 600;}
$f = fopen($filename, 'r');
$linenum = filesize($filename)/$linelength;

    for ($i=1; $i<=($linenum-$linenum_to_read);$i++) {
    $data = fread($f,$linelength);
    }
echo "<pre>";       
    for ($j=1; $j<=$linenum_to_read+1;$j++) {
    echo fread($f,$linelength);
    }

echo "</pre><hr />The filesize is:".filesize("$filename");
}

getlast("file.txt",6,230);


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Least amount of ram, and outputs well. I agree with Paul Dixon...

```
$lines=array();
$fp = fopen("userlog.txt", "r");
while(!feof($fp))
{
 $line = fgets($fp, 4096);
 array_push($lines, $line);
 if (count($lines)>25)
   array_shift($lines);
}
fclose($fp);

while ($a <= 10) {
$a++;
echo "<br>".$lines[$a];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dosya = "../dosya.txt";
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($dosya));
$reversed = array_reverse($array);
for($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++) 
{
    echo $reversed[$x];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While i love the elegant answers of [kamil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55634720/17471189) and [wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981383/17471189) i added an additional line for handling files that do not have as much lines as defined in $num.

```
function readLastLines($filename, $num, $reverse = false) {
    $file = new \SplFileObject($filename, 'r');
    $file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $last_line = $file->key();
    $first_line = $last_line - $num < 0 ? 0 : $last_line - $num;
    $lines = new \LimitIterator($file, $first_line, $last_line);
    $arr = iterator_to_array($lines);
    if($reverse) $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    return implode('', $arr);
}
```

Comment: This solution has to read every single line from the file, which make its complexity O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the fseek()-based solutions, which means the time it takes would depend on the file size, the bigger the slower.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution:

```
/**
 *
 * Reads N lines from a file
 *
 * @param type $file       path
 * @param type $maxLines   Count of lines to read
 * @param type $reverse    set to true if result should be reversed.
 * @return string
 */
public function readLinesFromFile($file, $maxLines, $reverse=false)
{
    $lines = file($file);

    if ($reverse) {
        $lines = array_reverse($lines);
    }

    $tmpArr = array();

    if ($maxLines > count($lines))
        exit("\$maxLines ist größer als die Anzahl der Zeilen in der Datei.");

    for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
        array_push($tmpArr, $lines[$i]);
    }

    if ($reverse) {
        $tmpArr = array_reverse($tmpArr);
    }

    $out = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
        $out .= $tmpArr[$i] . "</br>";
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Following ideas from Kamil and Volkmar in this thread:

```
function readLastLines($filename, $num, $reverse = false)
{
    $file = new \SplFileObject($filename, 'r');
    $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);  // fix when $num=1 (correct  PHP bug 65601)
    $file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $last_line = $file->key();
    $offset = max(0, $last_line - $num + 1);
    $lines = new \LimitIterator($file, $offset);
    $arr = iterator_to_array($lines);
    if($reverse) $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    return implode('',$arr);
}
```

Comment: This solution has to read every single line from the file, which make its complexity O(n) as opposed to O(1) for the fseek()-based solutions, which means the time it takes would depend on the file size, the bigger the slower.

Answer (score -3):

If your lines are separated by a CR or LF you would try [exploding](http://php.net/explode) your $data variable:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
```

$lines should end up being an array and you can work out the number of records using sizeof() and just get the last 5.

Comment: this will consume a lot of RAM making a huge array, for large file cases.

Comment: Also, this approach will not successfully delimit all line endings. As a bare minimum, `preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $data)` should be used. But then again, this is not the correct approach to OP's problem.

Answer (score -3):

this is read last 10 line from text file

```
$data = array_slice(file('logs.txt'),10);

    foreach ($data as $line) 

    {

        echo $line."<br/>";
    }
```