# how can I get php to read 5 lines instead of the whole .csv file?

Tags: php

```
$file_handle = fopen("ticker.csv", "r");  while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

  print '<div class="ticker_price">'. $line_of_text[7] . "</div>";
                                                                                                       }
fclose($file_handle);
```

How can I read a limited number of lines from the column 7 inside the .csv file

Comment: looks same like this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961618/how-to-read-only-5-last-line-of-the-txt-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small change to your code should read a maximum of five lines:

```
$maxLines = 5;
$file_handle = fopen("ticker.csv", "r");

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxLines && !feof($file_handle); $i++)
{
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print '<div class="ticker_price">'. $line_of_text[7] . "</div>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `fgets()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

It should be just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets to read file line by line and parse each line with str_getcsv

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

The fgetcsv function will give you an array representing one row. So to get at the nth column you have to loop through the rows and grab the nth value.

So if you wanted the 7th column up to the tenth row you could do

```
$row_from = 0;
$row_to = 10;
$row_counter = 0;
$7th_array = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024)) {
   if ($row_from <= $row_counter && $row_to >= $row_counter)
      $7th_array[] = $line[6];
   $row_counter++;
}
```

and you would have all the values from the 7th column in $7th_array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'file' to read the file into an array, then just grab each line, explode it into another array, then grab the index you want.